# Case-sensitive package names in pip under OSX

Tags: python, macos, pip, package

I'm trying to use pip (which I got via Anaconda; see version information below) to install a Python package called HTML.py

There are at least two unusual features about this package's name:

1. It ends with ".py"
2. It uses capital letters

I don't seem to be able to install the package. Running `pip install HTML.py` doesn't work, and if I drop the `.py` pip goes ahead and installs a different package instead, this one named `html`.

Can I get pip to install the package I want for me?

```
63-176-57-107:~ kuzzooroo$ pip search HTML.py
HTML.py                   - A Python module to easily generate HTML code
                            (tables, lists, ...). See
                            http://www.decalage.info/python/html for more
                            information.
odt2html.py               - Basic .odt to .html command line converter
63-176-57-107:~ kuzzooroo$ pip install HTML.py
Downloading/unpacking HTML.py
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement HTML.py
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for HTML.py
Storing complete log in /Users/kuzzooroo/.pip/pip.log
63-176-57-107:~ kuzzooroo$ pip install HTML
Downloading/unpacking HTML
  Downloading html-1.16.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package HTML

Installing collected packages: HTML
  Running setup.py install for HTML

Successfully installed HTML
```

Here's what version of Anaconda I'm using:

```
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:09) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Imported NumPy 1.7.1, SciPy 0.13.0, Matplotlib 1.3.1
Type "scientific" for more details.
```

BTW, pip works fine for other packages for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is a problem with pip. If you go to the PyPi page for HTML.py (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/HTML.py/0.04) that leads you to a download page of http://www.decalage.info/python/html .

However, there is no downloadable package on that page, and the author's BitBucket account doesn't list an HTML.py repo.

I think that for whatever reason, the author has pulled this package but hasn't updated PyPi.